# Throw error when properties marked with @JsonIgnore are passed

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson, deserialization

I have a requirement to mark certain properties in my REST beans as ignored using `@JsonIgnore`. (I am using Spring Boot). This helps in avoiding these properties in my Swagger REST documentation.

I also would like to ensure that if the client passes these properties, an error is sent back. I tried setting `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`, but that works only for properties that are truly unknown. The properties marked with `@JsonIgnore` passes through this check.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution -

If I add `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` to the field that is marked as `@JsonIgnore`, I get back a validation error. (I have also marked the property with `@Null` annotation. Here is the complete solution:

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Employee {
  @Null(message = "Id must not be passed in request")
  private String id;
  
  private String name;

  //getters and setters
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class EmployeeRequest extends Employee {
  @Override
  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
  public void setId(String id) {
    super.setId(id);
  }
}
```

PS: By adding `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)`, the property started showing up in Swagger model I had to add `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` to hide it again.
The create method takes `EmployeeRequest` as input (deserialization), and the get method returns `Employee` as response (serialization). If I pass `id` in create request, with the above solution, it gives me back a ConstraintViolation.

PS PS: Bummer. None of these solutions worked end-to-end. I ended up creating separate request and response beans - with no hierarchical relationship between them.

Comment: Nothing worked satisfactorily. I ended up creating different objects with no hierarchy for requests and responses.